# How to create jquery modal popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What am I doing wrong that this popup isn't working?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#dialog_link').click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog">testing popup</div>
<a href="#" id="dialog_link">click me</a>
```

Comment: You should  load jQuery UI. jQuery core doesn't have `dialog` method.

Comment: You should use jquery ui. Add these-

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/) also read the [doc](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default):

**html**

```
<a href="#" id="dialog_link">click me
    <div id="dialog">testing popup</div>
</a>
```

**jquery**

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
        effect: "show",
        duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "fadeOut",
        duration: 1000
    }
});

$("#dialog_link").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

**css**

```
#dialog_link {
    display: block;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zxk4eqbg/5/)

Those are the links from google host libraries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks.  The div is inside of an anchor tag, which is not valid.  Is there another way to do it so the div isn't always visible on the page?

Comment: Yes i know that it's correct. but i didn't want to change your html mark up. You can use any other element e.g [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6wx1nmh/)